# i have error like bad request while add product in shopify using api

Tags: php, shopify

Following errors has occured:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ShopifyApiException' with message 'Bad Request' in D:\xampp\htdocs\cutoutphoto\lib\shopify.php:87 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\cutoutphoto\lib\shopify.php(203): ShopifyClient->call('POST', '/admin/products...', '{"image":{"posi...') #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\cutoutphoto\requests.php(217): ShopifyClient->update_image('134789371', 'D:\xampp\tmp\ph...', 'tango-featured....') #2 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\cutoutphoto\lib\shopify.php on line 87`

Comment: so what's your question? You need add more information.

Comment: What is on the line 87 inside the shopify?, did you tried to use a try/catch? what are the parameters, you need to provide a complete question with more information.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the method or the lines where you have ShopifyClient->update_image() in a try...catch block

Eg:

```
try {

  ShopifyClient->update_image('134789371', '/location/of/the/file', ...); 

} catch(Exception $e){
  //do something with the Exception
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I think you might be getting the Bad Request error because you are not passing all the parameters to the API or sending those params in the incorrect format. Also, check if you are using the correct authentication credentials for the API.

Also, its helpful for us to answer questions if you do provide some more information like what is your code trying to do, post that block of code here, rather than just the stack trace. But I see this is your first post on Stack Overflow so don't mind :)